# Dont want the 1st position in array

Tags: java, arrays, sub-array

I have one array, say

```
String[] a={a,b,c,d,e,f,g}
```

I want this array in second array but without the first element in the array, for example

```
String[] b{b,c,d,e,f,g}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: i tried Arrays.copyofrange(myarray,1,-)
now how to find the end of the array??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.arrayCopy()` **(jdk 1.5)** or `Arrays.copyOfRange()` **(jdk 1.6+)**  methods.